# How set svg as background full screen?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've created a inline svg code as my background for my website but whenever i resize my window horizontally the is a empty space at the bottom of the website.
This is a example code for my website.
This the css for my website:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    }
```

The viewbox for my svg is 0 0 1920 902. The horizontal side of the svg is always attached to the side of the window. I wanted the size of the svg remains and user are able to scroll to see the overflow area but it does not work even after i added `overflow: scroll;` in body css.
[image: example]

Comment: Your Codepen example is working, showing no white space below the SVG

Comment: @ArtisticaDigital Have you tried it in full view mode and resize your window?

Comment: Yes; the gap at the bottom on Codepen, from what I can see using inspector, isn't part of your code.

Are you using inline SVG as a background for a specific reason?
You can use SVG as a standard CSS background image. If all the structural elements within an SVG take up the whole viewbox, you shouldn't have whitespace in the image

Answer (score 0):

New answer based on comments:

If you need a button strictly within one of the hexagons, one option is to place a rect/text within one of the hexagons. Then wrap this in a `<g>` (group) tag with appropriate class, then within an `<a>` tag, also with class or id. This is an SVG `<a>` rather than HTML, but works in a similar way).

You can't use HTML within SVG without a lot of extra work. To have an HTML over inline SVG you'll need to position the button absolute, or position the inline SVG absolute/fixed. With SVG as CSS background it's easier. You can ensure the button aligns with the background by using percentage or view width, however if you want true responsiveness you'll need to work out where the hexagon is percentage wise on the SVG. I'd recommend an SVG internal element wrapped in `<a>`, or just accepting the background won't fully align.

Old answer:

You can try width="100%" height="100%".
Otherwise, you can use an SVG editor to ensure the viewbox matches the SVG itself.
I use Adobe XD, Illustrator. You can use Inkscape.

Comment: I did used width="100%" height="100%" but I'm still having the same problem. I used Illustrator to design this and made sure that the design is fit to artwork bound.

Comment: In that case, please share further code, like bounding elements.

Comment: These are the main background code for now. The other codes is just only some extra hexagonal button and a background gradient. Does viewbox count as bounding elements?

Comment: No they don't. I suspect all you're seeing is where the SVG stops, and there's no more content.
Are you using inline SVG as a background for a specific reason?

Comment: Not really. It's just that i created the whole design with the hexagon button i mentioned just now together so i thought i would just use the background part as inline code as well. And i'm a bit worried that the hexagon button will not align with the background as it is not just some simple straight lines.

Comment: If you need a button strictly within one of the hexagons, another option is to place a rect/text within one of the hexagons. Then wrap this in a <g> (group) tag, then within an <a> tag. This is an SVG <a> rather than HTML, but works in a similar way).

Comment: You can't use HTML within SVG without a lot of extra work.
To have an HTML over inline SVG you'll need to position the button absolute, or position the inline SVG absolute/fixed. With SVG as CSS background it's easier. You can ensure the button aligns with the background by using percentage or view width, however if you want true responsiveness you'll need to work out where the hexagon is percentage wise on the SVG.
I'd recommend an SVG internal element wrapped in <a>, or just accepting the background won't fully align?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can select as chosen answer if you would like

Comment: Well this is not helping as the button works perfectly fine. That is why i only extract the background code out as the problem im facing is only the background. But still thank you for your effort to try to help me out.

Comment: You have multiple problems - so consider asking more than 1 question.
1. Why is there a gap in my background? Well your background doesn't have enough height, hence my answer above using repeating background using non-inline SVG or changing the image.
2. You want the button to be perfectly aligned to a hexagon- hence my other answer. 

How have I not helped? I gave you multiple answers to your specific problems